# How to use stringtemplate in Antlr (rewrite)

Tags: templates, url-rewriting, antlr

I would have this problem :
i given this rules

```
 expr: (NUM -> NUM) ( a=NUM -> ^(PLUS   $expr   $a ))* ;

    NUM   : '0'..'9'+;
    WS    :  ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'  ) {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

parses the input "1 2 3 4" as follows:

```
(PLUS (PLUS (PLUS  1  2)  3)  4)
```

my problem is how can i use 'template' or the file '.stg'  to get the output

```
1+2+3+4
```

the **wrong** stringtemplate rule

```
expr  :^(plus  a=multi  b=NUM )    ->template(f1={$a.st},f2={$b.st})"<f1>+<f2>"
```

Thank you, Bart Kiers!!!

Comment: `"1234"` is not being tokenized into 4 separate tokens: `NUM   : '0'..'9'+;`. will create a single token from it.